# Received cookie is not fully correct

Tags: android, cookies, httprequest

In my android application, after a post request I am getting cookie like this

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
String cookie = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie").getValue();
```

when I print the value of cookie in LogCat its value is  `PHPSESSID=150edfn1mmr4grmip6pd4h5pv6; path=/`

However, when I send post request via a tool or online site like hurl.it the returned cookie is  `PHPSESSID=150edfn1mmr4grmip6pd4h5pv6; path=/, abtesting=0`

Why httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie").getValue() returns lack of data? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As like many other Java HttpClient based implementations. This can be due to the processing of the headers since based on `Set-Cookie` specifications `abtesting=0` is an invalid attribute.

Although WikiPedia states `The value of a cookie may consist of any printable ascii character (! through ~, unicode \u0021 through \u007E) excluding , and ; and excluding whitespace. The name of the cookie also excludes = as that is the delimiter between the name and value. The cookie standard RFC2965 is more limiting but not implemented by browsers.` The key is RFC2965.

See the documentation associated with [HttpCookie](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html) it links to RFC documents which have specific syntax/values that must be followed.